# Reference to element of vector returned by a function in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, reference, return, return-by-value

Can someone verify that the following is a BUG, and explain why? I think I know, but am unclear about the details. (My actual problem involved a vector of enums, not ints, but I don't think it should matter.) Suppose I have the following code:

```
std::vector<int> f (void) {
  std::vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(5);
  return v;
}

void g (void) {
  const int &myIntRef = f()[0];
  std::cout << myIntRef << std::endl;
}
```

Am I correct that myIntRef is immediately a dangling reference, because the return value of f is saved nowhere on the stack?

Also, is the following a valid fix, or is it still a bug?

```
  const int myIntCopy = f()[0];  // copy, not a reference
```

In other words, is the return result of f() thrown away before the 0th element can be copied?

Comment: I'm just curious, but is there _ever_ any reason to use a `int const&` instead of an `int` as a local variable?

Comment: @JamesKanze: Maybe to mark the variable as `const`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is wrong thing to do indeed. When you call:

```
return v;
```

temporary copy of object `v` is being created and

```
const int &myIntRef = f()[0];
```

initializes your reference with the first element of this temporary copy. After this line, the temporary copy no longer exists, meaning that `myIntRef` is an invalid reference, using of which produces **undefined behavior**.

What you should do is:

```
std::vector<int> myVector = f();
const int &myIntRef = myVector[0];
std::cout << myIntRef << std::endl;
```

which (thanks to *copy elision*) uses an assignment operator to initialize `myVector` object by using `v` without copy of `v` being created. In this case the lifetime of your reference is equal to the lifetime of `myVector` object, making it perfectly valid code.

---

And to your second question:

> *"Also, is the following a valid fix, or is it still a bug?"*
>
> ```
>  const int myIntCopy = f()[0];  // copy, not a reference
> ```

Yes, this is another possible solution. `f()[0]` will access the first element of the temporary copy and use its value to initialize `myIntCopy` variable. It is guaranteed that the copy of `v` returned by `f()` exists at least until the whole expression is executed, see *C++03 Standard 12.2 Temporary objects §3*:

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

Answer (score 11):

That is a bug. At the end of the complete expression `const int &myIntRef = f()[0];` the temporary vector will be destroyed and the memory released. Any later use of `myIntRef` is undefined behavior.

Under some circumstances, binding a reference to a temporary can extend the lifetime of the temporary. This is not one of such cases, the compiler does not know whether the reference returned by `std::vector<int>::operator[]` is part of the temporary or a reference to an `int` with static storage duration or any other thing, and it won't extend the lifetime.

Comment: By the way, I added a follow-up question, if you feel so inclined :-).

Comment: @user2170028: Answer to your follow-up question is: Yes. See my answer :)

Comment: @user2170028: This answer already has the solution to your update: *at the end of the complete expression*, meaning after the assignment. If you make a copy, the copy will get the correct value. Only after the complete expression completes (`;`) the temporary is destroyed